# As + (Subject + Verb) omission

Tags: conjunctions, ellipses

In present tense or past tense, subject and verb can be omitted after conjunction.

For example

> - People tend to laugh when (they are) imagining pleasant things
> - When (I was) going home, I met my father

Then could it be possible to omit subject and verb in case of the past perfect tense as well?

For example,

> - As it had been written in a hurry, the report showed many errors.
> - As written in a hurry, the report showed many errors.

Or, because this case is of the past perfect tense is changing this way only correct?

> - (Having been) written in a hurry (without conjunction 'as'), the report showed many errors.

Comment: No I didn't post that question :)

Comment: Nobody is suggesting that you did, just that it provides an answer to _your_ question.